# Get average of rows with some conditions in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 3 columns with id,level1,level2.I need to get average of level 1 and level2 with respect to id.Same Id have multiple level1 and level2.

I tried to get unique rows for id..but average i couldnt.

```
+--------+----------+-----------+
   | id     | level1   | level2    |
   +--------+----------+-----------+
   |   1    |    2     |   4       |
   +--------+----------+-----------+
   |   1    |    3     |    5      |
   +--------+----------+-----------+
   |   1     |   1      |     4     |
   +--------+----------+-----------+
   |   2    |   3      |    5      |
   +--------+----------+-----------+
   |   2    |   4      |    2      |
   +--------+----------+-----------+
   |   2    |   5      |    3      |
   +--------+----------+-----------+
```

I need the output as like this.

```
 +--------+----------+-------------------+
   | id     | avg_level1   | avg_level2    |
   +--------+----------+-----------+--------
   |   1    |    2         |   4.33        |
   +--------+----------+-----------+-------+
   |  2     |    4        |    3.33        |
   +--------+----------+-----------+--------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ID,AVG(level1) avg_level1,AVG(level2)avg_level2
FROM TABLE GROUP BY ID
```

You can try above code.

Here I had used [`AVG`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-avg-function.htm) mysql inbuilt function for same.

Comment: what if we had separate condition on each average column, for example, if level1 must be 2 and above and level 2 must be 3 above